# Почему у std::log() в с++ только один аргумент?

Tags: c++, математика

Логарифм - это операция, которая определяет степень начального числа, что бы из начального числа получилось конечное число. Однако в std::log() можно записать один аргумент. Это как так? Если нормальный логарифм можно записать в виде следующего уравнения: a^x=b. Где а - начальное число, а число b конечное. Но вот я даже понятия не имею как записать std::log(), ведь я не знаю что значит этот самый единственный аргумент. Начальное число или конечное, или может ещё что нибудь. Просветите меня пожалуйста, я не понимаю

Comment: Прежде, чем задавать такие вопросы, [ознакомьтесь с документацией](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это натуральный логарифм, для вашего a = e = 2.718281828459045...

Для **любого** другого основания можно вычислить легко и просто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. ежели взять с = e, то получим, что для вычисления вашего логарифма надо просто написать

```
log(b)/log(a)
```

Кстати, если верить программе — все эти формулы учат в школе даже сейчас...

Comment: Если не трудно, то пожалуйста ответьте зачем используется для натурального логарифма именно число e(2.71828...) и что оно означает

Comment: "Кстати, если верить программе — все эти формулы учат в школе даже сейчас...". Наверное, но я только перешёл в седьмой класс, и нам ещё даже про корни чисел не обьясняли

Comment: @Dkslskx, вы задаёте вопросы из учебника. Проще, быстрее и правильнее будет прочитать учебник и понять почему *e* и чем оно такое особенное.

Comment: Это меняет дело, без проблем. e — это основание натуральных логарифмов, очень интересная константа, но рассказать о ней всерьез здесь не получится :( Но если хотите, вы можете воспользоваться логарифмами по основанию 10, например — [`log10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10), формула та же:  `log10(b)/log10(a)`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Было интересно, но пойду почитаю более обширно почему именно е

Comment: @Dkslskx, если очень кратко, то физический смысл *e* проявляется в формулах. Когда скорость изменения какой-то величины пропорциональна самой этой величине, то в формуле появляется *ln*

Comment: @avp Не обязательно :) Скорость распада пропорциональна количеству вещества, но говорят о периоде *полураспада*. В формуле появляется *логарифм*, но не обязательно натуральный. Именно из-за этой пропорциональности всех логарифмов.

Comment: Ну вот, например — [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB73Ynza-0o), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ro6dzGfajvE).

Comment: @Harry, спонтанный распад не слишком хороший пример,  хотя и там в формуле полураспада фигурирует  натуральный логарифм: *`T = ln(2) / L`* (L это постоянная распада, зависит от природы элемента).  Я имел в виду остывание тела, разряд конденсатора и т.п. взаимодействия со средой

Comment: @avp Но все это в принципе можно описать с помощью любого другого логарифма. С натуральным оно натуральнее :), но это не обязательное условие...